# Преобразовать [Character: [String]]

Tags: массивы, строки, swift

Есть массив:

```
var sortedData = [Character: [String]]
```

И нужно преобразовать в

```
var dataObject = [String: [String]]
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал вот так

```
for (key, value) in sortedData {

        dataObject.updateValue(value, forKey: String(key))

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, это не масив, а словарь (дикшинари). Соответственно у него есть пара "Ключ - значение". В вашем случае Character это ключ, а значение масив [String].

Привести тип целого дикшинори, насколько мне извесно, нельзя. Потому, советую вам в цикле пройтись по первому дикшионари, и записать информацию во второй при этом, нужно привести ключ к String:

```
var sortedData = [Character: [String]]()

sortedData = ["a":["string_A","secondString_A"], "b":["string_B","secondString_B"] ]

var secondData = [String:[String]]()

for i in sortedData.keys {
    secondData[String(i)] = sortedData[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

И все же в `Swift` лучше сделать `mapping` в новый `Dictionary`:

```
let dataObject = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: sortedData.map { (String($0), $1) })
```